# MC Gaussian distribution for inverter threshold voltage

Tags: matlab, gaussian, montecarlo

I need to overlap the MC gaussian distribution for threshold voltage generated using MATLAB and LTspice..If i use the same mean value(i.e 0.3558) and sigma value(3*sigma=10% i.e sigma=0.0333) for both my simulations then MATLAB distribution is much more wider than LTspice distribution..On the other hand if i use same mean value for both my simulations and sigma= 10% in LTspice and sigma =0.0333 in MATLAB then both the graphs overlay. But i need to incorporate the same value of sigma for both my simulations..May i know what's the relation between sigma and 3*sigma in LTspice and MATLAB respectively and how can i address this issue?

MATLAB code has been attached below.

```
n=     5000; %no of runs%
m=     0.3558; %nominal Vth/Mean%
sd=    0.0333; % 3*sigma standard deviation%
Vth=   m + sd*randn(n,1); %Gaussian distribution of Vth%
figure(2);
hist(Vth); %Histogram of Vth%`
```

LTspice Code for generating Gaussian distribution has been attached.

```
VTH1=.3558*(1+gauss(0.1)) % sigma=10%
```

Comment: What's your question? What is the relation between sigma and 3*sigma? The answer is a multiplication by 3.

Comment: i get the same results when i use sigma in LTspice and 3*sigma in MATLAB..But isn't it that i need to get same results when i use either sigma or 3*sigma in both my simulations?May i know why this difference?

Comment: Isn't the problem the way to express the gaussians? In your LTspice code you should just do the same as in Matlab: `m + sd*gauss(1.0)`. The problem is that in LTspice your code is equivalent to : `.3558 + (.3558*0.1)*randn()`. The problem is indeed that your factor .3558 impacts both mean and variance in your LTspice code.

Comment: But the way which i have adopted to generate gaussian distribution in LTspice and MATLAb is it right?Can i adopt either of the ways?

Answer (score 0):

`randn()` in Matlab generates random numbers with distribution (0,1).

`gauss(x)` in LTspice generates random numbers with distribution (0,x).

Therefore, if you want a number generated with distribution (m,v), you need to perform in Matlab:

```
m + v*randn();
```

and in LTspice:

```
m + gauss(v)
```

or if you want it to look like in Matlab:

```
m + v*gauss(1.0)
```

Comment: can i use this in MATLAB ? `.3558 + (.3558*0.1)*randn() `

Comment: Yes you can, or `.3558*(1.0 + 0.1*randn())`